# Javascript to jquery Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tomcat, cross-domain

I have some `Javascript` that's using `Ajax` to make a request to my `Tomcat` server.
I have a filter setup up on the `Tomcat` server to allow cross domain requests using:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This is the `Javascript` snippet that I have successfully making request to my `Tomcat` servelet:

```
$(function() {

// Set the default dates
var startDate = Date.create().addDays(-6), // 7 days ago
endDate = Date.create(); // today

var range = $('#range');

// Show the dates in the range input
range.val(startDate.format('{MM}/{dd}/{yyyy}') + ' - '
        + endDate.format('{MM}/{dd}/{yyyy}'));

// Load chart
ajaxLoadChart(startDate, endDate);

range.daterangepicker({
    startDate : startDate,
    endDate : endDate,
    ranges : {
        'Today' : [ 'today', 'today' ],
        'Yesterday' : [ 'yesterday', 'yesterday' ],
        'Last 7 Days' : [ Date.create().addDays(-6), 'today' ],
        'Last 30 Days' : [ Date.create().addDays(-29), 'today' ]
    }
}, function(start, end) {
    ajaxLoadChart(start, end);
});

// Function for loading data via AJAX and showing it on the chart
function ajaxLoadChart(startDate, endDate) {
    // If no data is passed (the chart was cleared)
    if (!startDate || !endDate) {
        return;
    }
    // Otherwise, issue an AJAX request
    $.post('http://192.168.1.6:8083/Servlet/PreProcessor', {
        start : startDate.format('{MM}/{dd}/{yyyy}'),
        end : endDate.format('{MM}/{dd}/{yyyy}')
    }, function(data) {
        if ((data.indexOf("No record found") > -1)
                || (data.indexOf("Date must be selected.") > -1)) {
            $('#msg').html('<span style="color:red;">' + data + '</span>');
        } else {
            $('#msg').empty();
            $('#chart').highcharts({
                chart : {
                    type : 'arearange',
                    zoomType : 'x'
                },

                title : {
                    text : 'Temperature variation by day'
                },

                xAxis : {
                    type : 'datetime'
                },

                yAxis : {
                    title : {
                        text : null
                    }
                },

                tooltip : {
                    crosshairs : true,
                    shared : true,
                    valueSuffix : '°C'
                },

                legend : {
                    enabled : false
                },

                series : [ {
                    name : 'Temperatures',
                    data : data
                } ]
            });
        }
    }, 'json');
    }
});
```

I'm trying to convert the `Javscript` `Ajax` request to `Jquery`, but I'm getting a `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` error and a `POST` error with my Jquery Ajax request:

```
$(function () {

// Set the default dates
var startDate = Date.create().addDays(-6), // 7 days ago
endDate = Date.create(); // today

var range = $('#range');

// Show the dates in the range input
range.val(startDate.format('{MM}/{dd}/{yyyy}') + ' - '
        + endDate.format('{MM}/{dd}/{yyyy}'));

// Load chart
ajaxLoadChart(startDate, endDate);

range.daterangepicker({
    startDate: startDate,
    endDate: endDate,
    ranges: {
        'Today': ['today', 'today'],
        'Yesterday': ['yesterday', 'yesterday'],
        'Last 7 Days': [Date.create().addDays(-6), 'today'],
        'Last 30 Days': [Date.create().addDays(-29), 'today']
    }
}, function (start, end) {
    ajaxLoadChart(start, end);
});

// Function for loading data via AJAX and showing it on the chart
function ajaxLoadChart(startDate, endDate) {
    // If no data is passed (the chart was cleared)
    if (!startDate || !endDate) {
        return;
    }


     // Otherwise, issue an AJAX request
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://192.168.1.6:8083/Servlet/PreProcessor',
            type: 'POST',
            crossDomain: true,
            async: true,
            dataType: "json",
            start: startDate.format('{MM}/{dd}/{yyyy}'),
            end: endDate.format('{MM}/{dd}/{yyyy}'),
            success: function (data) {
                defaultChart(data);
            }
        });
    }
});


function defaultChart(data) {
    if ((data.indexOf("No record found") > -1)
                     || (data.indexOf("Date must be selected.") > -1)) {
        $('#msg').html('<span style="color:red;">' + data + '</span>');
    } else {
        $('#msg').empty();
        $('#chart').highcharts({
            chart: {
            type: 'arearange',
            zoomType: 'x'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Temperature variation by day'
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            crosshairs: true,
            shared: true,
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Temperatures',
            data: data
        }]
    });
    }
}
```

I'm a novice with both `Jquery` and `Javascript` and can't see where I've gone wrong, research suggested to me that adding `crossDomain: true` to the Ajax Jquery request would set the header in the request, so maybe my code is the problem?

**EDIT**

Looking at this again is the first snippet using Jquery already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem with my code was the way that you add parameters to the `Ajax`request

My entail attempt was structured like so:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://192.168.1.6:8083/Servlet/PreProcessor',
        type: 'POST',
        crossDomain: true,
        async: true,
        dataType: "json",
        start: startDate.format('{MM}/{dd}/{yyyy}'),
        end: endDate.format('{MM}/{dd}/{yyyy}'),
        success: function (data) {
            defaultChart(data);
        }
    });
```

When it should have been structured like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://192.168.1.6:8083/IBMServlet_war/PreProcessor',
        crossDomain: true,
        async: true,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data:{ start: startDate.format('{MM}/{dd}/{yyyy}'), end : endDate.format('{MM}/{dd}/{yyyy}')},
        success: function (data) {
            defaultChart(data);
        }
    }).error(function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert("error");
            console.log(xhr);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The first code snippet is using jQuery. $Post syntactic sugar for using $.ajax with type="POST". I'm not sure why you would get a CORS error with the second code, but not the first. You can troubleshoot the headers using chrome developer tools to look the headers on the requests and responses. 

Alternatively, if you are posting to the same url, you can use a relative address instead of a fully qualified HTTP:// address.

Comment: i've been looking at the response / request headers in chrome and on the failed response header I'm missing the: `Access-control-Allow-Credentials: true`
and `Access-control-Allow-Origin: myurl`

Could it be anything to do with using the wild card in my filter on the tomcat server? I'v tried plugging in my domain instead of `/*` but it stops working.

Comment: By looking at the tomcat documentation (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter) I think you need to add an init-param for cors.exposed.headers to include these headers. Just do a search on the documentation page for an example.

Comment: I've narrowed the problem down to the `doPost` method on the server, if I don't aplly the `type: POST` to the Ajax request it half works, it defaults to `get` though and the dates aren't retrieved from the request so I get no response.

When I'm using ajax the way I am do i need to parse the request differently sever side?

Comment: $.ajax use method: "POST" NOT type: 'POST' as the parameter. I bet if you check the method coming from the broswer right now it will come across as a GET since that is the default for $.ajax.

Comment: I solved the problem thanks for you input, you spurred me onto the solution.

Comment: Glad you got it. Sorry I couldn't have been a bigger help.